# Mp3 has paused when screen locked

Tags: android, url, service, mp3

mp3 pauses when on screen lock..here is my main java code...I've searched some information but nothing helped me.And by the way After clicking Play, then stop, then back to play, the application force crashes, sometimes it requires more clicks, sometimes fewer..Can someone help me please..Thank you !

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private ProgressBar playSeekBar;

private Button buttonPlay;

private Button buttonStopPlay;

private MediaPlayer player;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    initializeUIElements();

    initializeMediaPlayer();
}
private void initializeUIElements() {

    playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    playSeekBar.setMax(100);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

}
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonPlay) {
        startPlaying();
    } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
        stopPlaying();
    }
}  
private void startPlaying() {
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    player.prepareAsync();

    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.start();
        }
    });

}

private void stopPlaying() {
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        initializeMediaPlayer();
    }

    buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource("http://users1.jabry.com/mine/inna.mp3");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
            Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should debug the project and find the exceptions yourself.

Comment: @LaiVung if i could sure i ll ve did :( but nothing found it about gotcha?

Answer (score 1):

When the screen is locked your onPause is being called, and you are explicitly stopping the player there.

Comment: If you want to have things run in the background, even when the screen is locked, you might consider using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).